# Replicate Add button functionality on FormDetail screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to create the button to replicate when user click "+" button on the top of the screen then populate value of the field.

```
Base.Insert.Press();
```

However, I have an issue that code above does not clear the form like when user click "+" button.  I need to be able to clear the form after insert like when click Acumatica's "+" button.  I have try following code in attempt to clear the form but no luck.

```
Base.Caches.Clear();
Base.Document.Cache.Clear();
Base.Document.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
Base.Document.View.RequestedRefresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works in Sales order extension. What I did is; I cleared the whole graph and then inserted a new header record to the header cache.

```
 this.Base.Clear();
 SOOrder head = new SOOrder();
 this.Base.Document.Insert(head);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I try this on my Sales Order extension, it does not clear the header for me.

Comment: did you try to debug the code? I tried this in acumatica ERP 5.1

Comment: I did debug the code and it's ran through correctly.  this.Base.Document.Current values are changed but on page still not refresh.  I try it on ERP 5.10.0537.